# How can I access the HTML Form Name from the Java servlet?

Tags: html, servlets

I am facing an issue where a single java servlet needs to handle multiple HTML forms. So, I thought of using Form names in the HTML to pass it on to the server.

Like,
Form 1:

```
form method="POST" action='Controller' name="edit1"
```

Form 2:

```
form method="POST" action='Controller' name="edit2"
```

How can I access both these forms from a single servlet?

Answer (score 6):

Form name is not sent with the HTTP request on submit, thus it cannot be used on the server side.

Consider adding hidden field with the same name but different values in both forms:

```
<form method="POST" action='Controller'>
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="form1" />
  <!-- ... -->
</form>

<form method="POST" action='Controller'>
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="form2" />
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

And in your servlet:

```
request.getParameter("type");
```

Comment: @user757021: Glad I could help. Please accept an answer or provide further details if you still find some problems.

Answer (score 1):

Basics:

> When we submit a form all the values of that form will only get
>   submitted.. So even if you are having two forms and you are submitting
>   one of them, then only parameters of submitted form will be available
>   to your controller.

```
<form method="POST" action='Controller' name="form1">
  <input type="text" name="type" value="form1Text" />
  <input type="text2" name="type" value="form1Text2" />
  <input type="submit"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</form>

<form method="POST" action='Controller' name="form2">
  <input type="text" name="type" value="form2Text" />
  <input type="text2" name="type" value="form2Text2" />
  <input type="submit"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Pressing Submit button with submit the respective form.