# Get name of the form in servlet

Tags: html, forms, servlets

```
<form name="GetAll"
      method="post"
      action="NewServlet">
            <input type="text" name="des">
            <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How I can get name of this form (`GetAll`) in my `NewServlet` servlet?

Comment: The `name` attribute of an HTML form is not submitted as part of an HTTP request. You can instead embed the name in a hidden form field. Where is it needed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1252125/1391249, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8807850/1391249

Answer (score 2):

The name attribute of the form is not part of the HTTP request when it is submitted. You could add a hidden field instead to identify multiple forms off same page like

```
<input type="hidden" name="formName" value="formA">
```

keeping the name attribute of the hidden input same of course.